# Are there any improvements I can make to my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, browserify

I have recently started using browserify and have created a custom module to toggle two menus based on the ID clicked and apply a transparent overlay effect. behind the menu. I have got it working but just wanted to get some feedback on whether it can improved performance or coding-wise as I am wanting to improve my JS skills.

```
/**
* Require modules
*/
var dullBackground = require('./dullBackground');

/**
* Export module
*/
module.exports = function() {

  'use strict';

  /**
  * Selectors
  */
  var menu = document.querySelector('#nav-main'),
      panel = document.querySelector('#overlay-panel'),
      productsPanel = document.querySelector('#products-panel'),
      systemsPanel = document.querySelector('#systems-panel'),
      close = document.querySelector('#overlay-close'),
      activeClass = "active",
      hideClass = "hide";

  /**
  * Methods
  */
  function togglePanel (event) {

    // Selectors
    var element = event.target,
        elementId = element.id;

    event.preventDefault();

    // Conditions
    if(elementId === 'page-products' || elementId === 'page-systems') {
      dullBackground();
      panel.classList.add(activeClass);
    }
    if(elementId === 'page-products') {
      productsPanel.classList.remove(hideClass);
    }
    if(elementId === 'page-systems') {
      systemsPanel.classList.remove(hideClass);
    }

  }
  function closePanel (event) {

    // Actions
    panel.classList.remove(activeClass);
    event.preventDefault();

    // Conditions
    if (!productsPanel.classList.contains(hideClass)) {
      productsPanel.classList.add(hideClass);
    }
    if (!systemsPanel.classList.contains(hideClass)) {
      systemsPanel.classList.add(hideClass);
    }

  }

  /**
  * Events/APIs/init
  */
  menu.addEventListener('click', togglePanel, false);
  close.addEventListener('click', closePanel, false);

};
```

Comment: Please post this to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: I agree that this is more of a code review question but I will quickly push the [Javacsript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables)'s idea that you should use a `var` statement for each variable you declare. I've gotten bitten by globaling things wrong with that.

Comment: Hey guys, never used code review so wasn't aware of this. I will repost, but thanks for your initial comment, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In performance perspective , I found 2 things your code is lacking of :

1. Use getElementById insteadof querySelector : getElementById is much faster than querySelector.

   2. Use Chaining as following :

   var elemId = event.target.id;

instead of

```
var element = event.target,
        elementId = element.id;
```